# how to set original state after category filter for lowest price to highest in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my codesandbox link. https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-lederberg-d2h508?file=/src/Components/Products/Products.js In this filtering when i click highest price its showing correcly and when i again click all filters how can i set back to its original state. please provide any solution for this.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Products from "./Components/Products/Products";
import SearchInput from "./Components/SearchInput/SearchInput";
import data from "./utils/data";

const App = () => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [productsInfo, setProductsInfo] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const selectedChangeFilter = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    if (value === "sporting goods") {
      const sportingGoods = data.filter(
        (product) => product.category === "Sporting Goods"
      );
      setProductsInfo(sportingGoods);
    }
    if (value === "electronics") {
      const electronicsGoods = data.filter(
        (product) => product.category === "Electronics"
      );
      setProductsInfo(electronicsGoods);
    }
    if (value === "lowest price") {
      const lowestPriceGoods = data.sort((el1, el2) =>
        el1.price.localeCompare(el2.price, undefined, { numeric: true })
      );
      setProductsInfo([...lowestPriceGoods]);
    }
    if (value === "highest price") {
      const highestPriceGoods = data.sort((el1, el2) =>
        el2.price.localeCompare(el1.price, undefined, { numeric: true })
      );
      setProductsInfo([...highestPriceGoods]);
    }
    if (value === "all") {
      setProductsInfo(data);
    }
  };

  const searchProducts = (products) => {
    if (searchValue.toLowerCase().trim() === "") {
      setProductsInfo(products);
    } else {
      const seekedItem = productsInfo.filter(
        (product) =>
          product.name.toLowerCase().trim().includes(searchValue) ||
          product.category.toLowerCase().trim().includes(searchValue)
      );
      setProductsInfo(seekedItem);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchInput
        handleChange={handleChange}
        searchValue={searchValue}
        selectedChangeFilter={selectedChangeFilter}
      />
      <Products
        data={data}
        searchValue={searchValue}
        productsInfo={productsInfo}
        searchProducts={searchProducts}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

I try this but it doesn't work

```
if (value === "all") {
const copiedData = [...data]
  setProductsInfo(copiedData);
}
```

Best regards

Comment: `sort()` is in place and also returns the array. so where you have `const highestPriceGoods = data.sort()` and `const lowestPriceGoods = data.sort()` you should change `data` to `[...data]` and have `[...data].sort()`.

Comment: see [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#return_value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#return_value)